# Google Play and the "Priced Status" filtering

Tags: android, google-play

I was thinking if this fits to stackoverflow (please tell me where to migrate it if it doesn't), but I'm a developer and it's a dev related question so not sure where else to ask.

Quoting [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html#other-filters) official Android page:

> Not all users can see paid apps. To show paid apps, a device must have
>   a SIM card and be running Android 1.1 or later, and it must be in a
>   country (as determined by SIM carrier) in which paid apps are
>   available.

Is this outdated? How users of tablets without a SIM card buy paid apps then?